# Getting server status with Python and Account API key in Pterodactyl Control Panel

Tags: python, python-3.x, server, discord.py

is there a way to get the server status of a server that is using the Pterodactyl Control Panel? I want to make a Discord Bot that has a command that says the status of the server, like online or offline using an Account API. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

https://dashflo.net/docs/api/pterodactyl/v1/
Everything is documented.
It's not their official API but its well documented, From what I understood is you want to make a discord bot with a command that shows the status of the server on pterodactyl.
You would need to make a request first to list all the servers. With a client key.
Through `/api/client`
Then get the `external_id` of the server you want to view the status of then make a request to `/api/client/servers/external_id` with the required headers that are listed in the documentation.

I hope this helped,
Cheers!